# Error building association with two foreign_key references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have a User and Recommendation model. User has several account types: student, admin, recommender, etc. Student users can assign recommenders to submit a recommendation. I am not using Rolify so

I currently have:

```
    class Recommendation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
    belongs_to :writer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "writer_id"
    end

    class User < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :recommendations_via_assigning, class_name: "Recommendation", foreign_key: :assigner_id
     has_many :recommendations_via_writing, class_name: "Recommendation", foreign_key: :writer_id


    class CreateRecommendations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
        create_table :recommendations do |t|

          t.integer :writer_id, foreign_key: true
          t.integer :assigner_id, foreign_key: true
          t.text    :text

          t.timestamps
        end
        add_index :recommendations, :writer_id
        add_index :recommendations, :assigner_id
      end
    end
```

Controller

```
     def new
     @recommendation = current_user.recommendations_via_assigning.build
     end

     def create
         @recommendation = current_user.recommendations_via_assigning.build(recommendation_request_params)
         if @recommendation.save
           @recommendation.send_invitation_email
           flash[:info] = "An email with submission instructions has been sent to the recommender you have invited."
           redirect_to user_url
         else
           render 'new'
         end
       end

     private
     def recommendation_request_params
         params.require(:recommendation).permit(:assigner_id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :relationship)
       end

       def recommendation_content_params
         params.require(:recommendation).permit(:writer_id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :text)
       end
```

I am unable to save a recommendation as it requires the writer_id, which won't be known when recommendation#create is submitted. What needs to happen is an email is issued to the provided email address inviting the teacher to create an account and when that account is registered, the recommendation by id with the writer_id of the teacher account.

How do I modify the existing code so I can pass recommendation#create without a writer_id?

Answer (score 0):

> unknown attribute 'user_id' for Recommendation so I assume I am not setting this up correctly.

Yes, you're providing `user_id` as a foreign key, but `user_id` column doesn't exist in the recommendation table. You need either rename `assigner_id` to `user_id` or remove `:foreign_key` settings, since `Rails` can figure it out by convention:

```
class Recommendation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: "User"
end
```

One note though about `has_many :recommendations`. This line actually requires `user_id` to exist in `recommendations` table. `Rails` can't figure out, whether you expect recommendations via writing of via assigning. Here you might want to provide `foreign_key` option according to the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recommendations_via_assigning, class_name: "Recommendation", foreign_key: :assigner_id
  has_many :recommendations_via_writing, class_name: "Recommendation", foreign_key: :writer_id
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I am confused on how to work with recommendations_via_assigning and ""via_writing. Say I have a student creating recommendation #1, to create a recommendation resource would I then use @user.recommendations_via_assigning.build? And for a teacher user to update that recommendation, would I then use @user.recommendations_via_writing and pass the updated parameters? I am lost on how building a recommendation_via_assigning without indicating the writer_id would work or if that's something I need to do.

Comment: Following up, do I need to then create two controllers recommendations_via_assigning and recommendations_via_writing for this?

Comment: can a recommendation have an assigner_id and writer_id at the same time?

Comment: yes, assigner_id would be student and writer_id would be teacher. Will be posting updated post with new questions

Comment: I mean, can assigner_id and writer_id be not-nil at the same time? Can a recommendation be given by a teacher and a student at the same time?